# How to import a vue component interpolating its path?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I would like to import a list of components using vite like this:

```js
defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`${path}.vue`))
```

But I get a MIME type error.

Comment: Please, don't describe the error but list it. How does the app run? Also debugging info on the failed request is necessary

Comment: you must have a path prefix to do dynamic import. Example : `import(\`../pages/${pageName.value}.vue\`)`

Answer (score 0):

Vite cannot import nested dynamic paths:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import

That's because Vite is a packer and it needs to resolve paths statically.

If you want a folder path just use `import.glob`:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

You can find all files you need with a pattern:

```
const modules = import.glob('./components/*.vue');
```

Then when you need component dynamically you search it `modules` by a file path and get an import function to load it dynamically.

Note that all components found with `import.glob` arent treeshakable, so they all will be included in the bundle regardless whether you use them in the app or not.